# Thunk/Axios Dispatch Doing Nothing

Tags: reactjs, rest, redux, react-redux, redux-thunk

I created an action creator that is simply supposed to make a get request to my API and return with a list of all projects. However, for some reason, my return dispatch in my thunk function is not firing at all. It gets to the console.log() statement and just ends. There are no consoles errors, and no network calls being made either as far as I can tell. Any ideas why it would do absolutely nothing?

Dashboard.js (component)

```
import ProjectItem from "../Project/ProjectItem";
import styles from "./Dashboard.module.css";
import CreateProjectButton from "../CreateProjectButton/CreateProjectButton";
import { connect } from "react-redux";
import { getProjects } from "../../Redux/getProjects/actions";

const Dashboard = props => {
  useEffect(() => {
    console.log("blah");
    getProjects();
  }, []);

  return (
    <div className={styles.dashboardContainer}>
      <h1>Projects</h1>
      <br />
      <CreateProjectButton />
      <br />
      <hr />
      <ProjectItem />
    </div>
  );
};

const mapStateToProps = state => {
  return {
    projects: state
  };
};

const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => {
  return {
    getProjects: () => dispatch(getProjects())
  };
};

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(Dashboard);
```

action.js (action creator)

```
import { GET_PROJECTS_SUCCESS, GET_PROJECTS_ERROR } from "./constants";

export const getProjectsSuccess = payload => {
  console.log("getProjectSuccess", payload);
  return {
    type: GET_PROJECTS_SUCCESS,
    payload
  };
};

export const getProjectsError = () => {
  console.log("there was an error");
  return {
    type: GET_PROJECTS_ERROR
  };
};

export function getProjects() {
  console.log("getProject");
  return dispatch => {
    axios
      .get("/project/all")
      .then(res => dispatch(getProjectsSuccess(res.data)))
      .catch(err => dispatch(getProjectsError(err)));
  };
}
```

index.js (getProject reducer)

```
const initialState = {
  projects: [], //array of projects
  project: {}, // single project for update case
  reRender: false
};

const getProjectsReducer = (state = initialState, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case GET_PROJECTS_SUCCESS:
      return { ...state, projects: action.payload }; // will need to change action.payload later on
    default:
      return state;
  }
};

export default getProjectsReducer;
```

constants.js

```
export const GET_PROJECTS_SUCCESS = "GET_PROJECTS_SUCCESS";
export const GET_PROJECTS_ERROR = "GET_PROJECTS_ERROR";
```

rootReducer.js

```
import createProjectReducer from "./createProject/index";
import getProjectsReducer from "./getProjects/index";

const rootReducer = (state = {}, action) => {
  return {
    project: createProjectReducer(state.project, action),
    projects: getProjectsReducer(state.projects, action)
  };
};

export default rootReducer;
```

Answer (score 0):

FIXED: After reading up on the use effect hook in functional components I realized I was missing props.getProjects in the useEffect function in dashboard.js!